# Enforcing the contour range and reverse the color label

Tags: colors, gnuplot, contour

I'm using the following script

```
set term pngcairo font ",18" enh size 1400,1400                                                                                                                                                                                              
set view map                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
set key at screen 1, 0.9                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
unset surface                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
set contour base                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set cntrparam levels incremental 0.00, 0.06, 2                                                                                                                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
set linetype 2  lc rgb "#8F2FFF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 3  lc rgb "#8F2FFF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 4  lc rgb "#8F2FFF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 5  lc rgb "#2F30FF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 6  lc rgb "#2F30FF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 7  lc rgb "#2F8EFF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 8  lc rgb "#2F8EFF"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 9  lc rgb "#2FFFD6"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 10 lc rgb "#2FFFD6"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 11 lc rgb "#35FF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 12 lc rgb "#35FF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 13 lc rgb "#FEFF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 14 lc rgb "#FEFF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 15 lc rgb "#FFAF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 16 lc rgb "#FFAF2F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 17 lc rgb "#FF362F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set linetype 18 lc rgb "#FF362F"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
set xra[0.:12]                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
set yra[0.:12]                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
set xtics out nomirror                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
set ytics axis in offset -4.0,0 nomirror                                                                                                                                                                                                     
set out "foo.png"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
splot sin(x) * cos(y) w l lw 4
```

to obtain the following figure
[image]

My problem right now is that although I have used `set cntrparam levels incremental 0.00, 0.06, 2` I still get the maximum contour value `0.96`. Could anyone tell me how I can enforce gnuplot to fix the contour range to `2`. The second question is that: is it possible to reverse the color label order so that it starts from lower to higher values? In other words, I would like gnuplot to show value zero at the top of the label with magenta line and so on up to the highest value at the bottom of the label with red line.

Answer (score 2):

The function `sin(x)*cos(y)` is bounded from above by `1` so therefore the maximum contour level you get is 0.96 since the next one would be 1.02 (with step of 0.06), but there are no real values of `x,y` which would correspond to this hypothetical contour.

As for the order of the titles in the legend, `set key invert` does not seem to have an effect here. However, you might just invert the order in which Gnuplot constructs the contour lines, i.e., use

```
set cntrparam levels incremental 0.96, -0.06, 0
set isosamples 1000,1000 #to get smoother contours...
```

instead of `set cntrparam levels incremental 0.00, 0.06, 2`.